# Filter the Particular Tag content from PHP Variable?

Tags: php

I have the following value in $img_info variable...

```
<p><img src="images/a.jpg" alt="" />Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi eu ullamcorper felis.</p>
```

How I filter or retrieve particular `img tag` content only from `$img_info` Variable? 
Is there **any function available** in PHP without using `explode()`?...

Please anyone help me...

Comment: So the expected output is just `<p>Lorem ipsum dolor ...</p>`?

Comment: img tag content only Jack: I need <img src="images/a.jpg" alt="" /> from $img_info variable...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`DOMDocument`](http://php.net/domdocument) for that:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($img_info);

echo $dom->saveXML($dom->getElementsByTagName('img')->item(0));
```

Output:

```
<img src="images/a.jpg" alt="" />
```

Comment: Thanks 4 ur answer Jack... But I have using 5.3.5...It shows Warning: DOMDocument::saveHTML() expects exactly 0 parameters, 1 given in E:\xampp\htdocs\test.php on line 17

Comment: @Vasu Then just use `->saveXML()` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is [preg_match()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php)

```
$img_info = '<p><img src="images/a.jpg" alt="" />Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi eu ullamcorper felis.</p>';
preg_match('/\<img\s+(?:.*?)\/\>/i', $img_info, $rgMatches);
var_dump($rgMatches[0]);
```

such kind of problems usually resolved via regex, so knowing them will be very useful

Comment: Thanks Alma Do Mundo... May I know the explanations of '/\<img\s+(?:.*?)\/\>/i' within preg_match Alma Do Mundo...

Comment: Symbols `/../` delimits regex inside, modifier `i` indicates case-insensitive search. `\s` is for whitespace characters, `+` is repeating 1 or more times. `?:` means not to capture group in result, `.` is for any character and `*` means repeat 0 or more times.